# Why choose σ versus σσ in Hebrew loans?

Tags: greek, phonology, transliteration, loanwords, hebrew

The LXX provides a wide variety of Hebrew, Aramaic, and other Semitic words transcribed into Greek. Most of the transcriptions are straightforward: the letter lamedh *ל*, for example, is always transcribed as lambda *λ*.

However, the letter shin *שׁ* is less consistent. At the beginning of a word, it's always written with a single sigma *σ*. But between vowels, it's sometimes written with a *double* sigma *σσ*.

For example:

- *מָשִׁיחַ‎* > *Μεσσίας* (double sigma)
- *יֵשׁוּעַ* > *Ἰησοῦς* (single sigma)

What affects the decision to use one versus the other?

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6510/how-did-%CF%83%CF%83-differ-from-%CF%83

Comment: There are also a couple of odd spellings with upsilon before or after the sigma: Συμεών, Μωυσῆς. I wonder if this is because the Semitic [ʃ] was rounded.

Comment: We need to look it up in Knobloch, Frederick W, "Hebrew sounds in Greek script: Transcriptions and related phenomena in the Septuagint, with special focus on Genesis" (1995).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: this answer is pure speculation (or original research, if you're feeling generous), not backed up by any scholarly references.

Neither Varro nor I marked vowel length in our Hebrew and Aramaic transcriptions. But what if we go back and add that?

- מְשִׁיחַ‎ *məšīaħ* → *messias*
- יֵשׁוּעַ *jēšūaʕ* → *iēsūs*
- אַבְשָׁלוֹם *'abəšālōm* → *abessalōm*
- הוֹשֵׁעַ *hōšēaʕ* → *hōsēe*
- אֱלִישָׁע *'əlīšāʕ* → *elisaie*

For a few more examples:

- בָּשְׂמַת *bāsəmath* → *basemath*
- אֱלִישֶׁבַע *'əlīšebhaʕ* → *elisabet*
- עֵשָׂו *ʕēsāw* → *ēsau*
- יְהוֹשָׁפָט‬ *jəhōšāphāṭ* → *iōsaphat*
- בַשָׂמ *basām* → *balsamon* (*)

A pattern seems clear: **a double sigma is used after a short vowel, a single sigma after a long one**.

(A single sigma is also used word-initially and after a consonant, but that's less interesting, since no native Greek word has a double sigma in either of those environments.)

(*) This loan presumably happened earlier, before `/ɬ/` merged into `/s/`. But it still shows a double consonant after a short vowel in the Greek transcription.

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion. If correct it would point to a phenomenon in Hebrew, not one in Greek. Something like a rule in pre-Masoretic Hebrew that shin takes dagesh forte after a short or ultra-short vowel. It might be compared with the way that initial consonants are doubled after the article ha-.

Comment: Interesting! This raises (to me at least) the question whether they were all initially double sigma but gemination was dropped after a long vowel as somehow redundant. Or perhaps the quality of shin depended on the length of the preceding vowel or the Greeks heard so. There are [Greek words with a double sigma after a long vowel](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10999/79), but my impression is that they were pretty rare. Should we have a question whether this rule is as consistent as your preliminary research suggests?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if this pattern also holds up with ס (samekh).

Comment: @TKR Indeed! I'm going to see if I can find a proper list of Semitic loans in the Septuagint, which I can then search for medial sigmas (sigmata?), and compare against the original…it'll be a lot more scientific than my current "Google for Old Testament names and look for ones with S's in them".

Comment: @fdb Apparently also Aramaic, since the first vowel of "messias" is long in Hebrew (מָשִׁיחַ‎) but short in Aramaic (מְשִׁיחָא‎)

Answer (score 3):

I think that TKR's remark on the occasional spellings with υ may also be relevant to the matter.  Note that in Ἰησοῦς with the single σ, the the ש is in the vicinity of a rounded vowel.

Also interesting is that while שְלֹמֹה (Shelomo/Solomon) is Σαλωμῶν (or a variant), אַבְשָׁלוֹם (Abshalom/Absalom) is Αβεσσαλωμ, with medial σσ.  Also note אֲבִשַׁי (Abishai) -> Αβεσσα (σσ); הוֹשֵׁעַ (Hoshea/Hosea) -> Ωσηε (σ, rounded vowel).

For υ, also note שְׁכֶם (Shechem) -> Συχεμ (but also Σικιμα)

It looks to me like there is at least a partial correlation based on whether a rounded vowel is in the vicinity of the שׁ, but it cannot be regarded as predicative (in fact, I've mentioned a counter-example elsewhere: אֱלִישָׁע (Elisha) -> Ελισαιε).

Comment: Interesting! So if I'm understanding right, you're saying that a single sigma was used initially and adjacent to a rounded vowel, while a double sigma was used elsewhere?

Comment: @Draconis that might be putting it a bit too strongly, but I think there was a tendency to do that.

Comment: The ypsilon of Συχεμ is surely /i/, not a rounded vowel.