# Does any Greek word have a geminate consonant after a long vowel?

Tags: vowel-quantity, phonology, hebrew, loanwords, transcription

[I recently noticed a pattern in loans from Hebrew into Greek](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10998/406): the letter *šin* (or *sin*, or *łin* if you're really archaic) is transcribed *σσ* after a short vowel, *σ* elsewhere.

My knowledge of Classical Hebrew and Aramaic is weak, so this gemination might be a feature of those languages for all I know. But off the top of my head, I also can't think of any Greek word with a doubled consonant after a long vowel.

Does any such word exist? Metrical evidence won't do us any good here, since the doubled consonant would make the syllable long by position—but *η* and *ω* have their length shown clearly in writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the word *γλῶσσα* and a great number of other words derived from it.
[Here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=wss&lang=greek) is a list of words containing *-ωσσ-*, giving more examples.

Comment: And Attic *glôtta*!

Comment: @Cerberus Indeed! I should have rummaged deeper into the attic of my memory for suitable glottary.

Comment: ♦: Or dive deep into the isogloss, which must lie somewhere in the Aegean.

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few, actually. Just to add some more examples:

ἥττων "less"

πράττω "do" (impv. πρᾶττε shows the length)

πλήττω "strike"

μᾶλλον "more"

ἤλλαγμαι, pf. m./p. of ἀλλάττω "exchange"

ἡλλόμην, impf. of ἅλλομαι "jump"