Transliterating the name "Muhammad" to Greek
This blog claims that
""The proper interpretation of the Number of The Beast has been applied to Muhammad.  Maometis being a Greek rendering of his name that has a Gemetria value of 666.
Critics of that theory say the proper Greek rendering of Muhammad should be Maometh or Mouchoumet.  But those were contemporary Byzantine Greek transliterations.  A NT era Greek rendering in the rules of Koine Greek would have to end with a Sigma being a male proper name of foreign origin.  This rule of Koine Greek is the reason we are used to having an S at the end of Jesus and Moses.  David Thorn should have remembered this."
https://midseventiethweekrapture.blogspot.com/2016/02/maometis-al-mahdi-and-islamic.html?m=1
Are these valid rules in Koine Greek, and what would be the legitimate translation of the word?

In the New Testament (written in Koine Greek), you have plenty of Hebrew names that do not conform to Greek declension rules, including:

Abraham (Ἀβραὰμ)
Isaac (Ἰσαάκ)
Jacob (Ἰακώβ)
David (Δαυὶδ)

Note that the latter name also ends in a -d, just like Muhammad.
Some names, when they were easy to do so, were declined in Greek, such as Solomon (Σολομὼν) and Uriah (v. ἐκ τῆς τοῦ Οὐρίου in Matthew 1.6). When they were living people, the names were more likely to be declined (cf. Josephus, Ἰώσηπος in Greek), but clearly as you can see from above, there is no hard and fast rule that all names had to be declined, especially foreign names not given to living people.
What's more suspect though is choosing Maometis as the Greek rendering of Muhammad, clearly chosen deliberately to get to 666. You can't do the same, though, if you directly transcribe the Arabic Muḥammad into Greek, which, even ignoring the doubled consonant (kept in names like Μανασσῆς and—undeclined—Ναασσών), you should instead get something like Μουχαμαδας, yielding a whopping 1,356 instead.
Note that the letter ح in Muhammad's name corresponds to the Hebrew ח, which you find represented in names like Ῥαχάβ in Matthew, though in the epistles of James and Hebrews, you see it transcribed as Ῥαὰβ instead. Notice that neither transcription decline the name (female names were also declined in Greek, not just male ones). Even without the chi, it would still add up to 753.
More importantly, though, this shows that there is not just one way to transcribe a name in Greek, and not just with Hebrew. Depending on who you're reading, the name 'Assur-bani-apli' was rendered Σαρδανάπαλλος (typical) or Σαρδανάπαλος (rarer), and with gematria, one letter makes a huge difference. In Hecataeus and Herodotus, Artaphernes is Ἀρταφρένης, while in Thucydides and thereafter he's Ἀρταφέρνης, maybe no difference numerically, but shows still a difference. For a more divergent example, if you look at Greek names for pharaohs, you can see just how wildly different they can be (check out especially dynasty 15).
It's therefore without any merit to say that Μαομετις must have been how NT authors would have transliterated it. That blogger's understanding of Greek transliteration is woefully inadequate, and tying the name to 666 is pure anachronistic, religious motivation.

could you please answer a similar question here https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/49062/46343

Sorry if I keep bothering people with this, I wish to stop

(Tiny correction, Ναασσών נַחְשׁוֹן doesn't have a geminate originally; this seems to be a case of "double sigma after short vowel" as proposed by Draconis here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10998/40)

@TKR Thanks for the correction! I'll find a better example soon.

Cmw's answer is excellent, but I'd like to touch on one specific point of it. You ask "what would be the legitimate translation of the word". But there is no the legitimate transcription. Even in modern-day English, you'll see Muhammad, Mohemmed, and Muḥammad (with the dot), used by different people for different purposes. And that's in an era where you can go online and find an Arabic dictionary in a matter of seconds!
Even between Latin and Greek, two languages that were in contact for a long time and had a huge number of bilingual speakers, there's not always a single "correct" way to transcribe between them. For languages like Hebrew, it's much, much worse. For Arabic, well…the Book of Revelation was written in the first century CE, a good half a millennium before Muhammad was even born.
So even if we had a time machine, to take some educated native speakers of Koine Greek and some educated native speakers of Muhammad-era Arabic and put them in a room together, it's very unlikely we'd end up with a single consistent transcription. There's a reason gematria and similar traditions tend to be restricted to one particular language!
