# What was the sibilant in θάλασσα?

Tags: greek, pronunciation, alphabet, phonology

The word θάλασσα *thálassa* "sea" is spelled in various different ways, with different letters replacing the sigmas: some dialects had a tau, for example, while others had a theta.

Do we know (through loans and cognates, for example, or transcriptions into other languages) what underlying sound these various letters were representing?

Comment: It's not just this word -- Attic ττ : other dialects σσ is a regular pattern. (In this word there is Cretan θαλαθθα too -- I don't know if Cretan has θθ in other such words.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can only speculate about the exact *underlying* nature of the ["foreign phoneme"](http://www.jiesonline.com/issues/protected/jies3712/14(191-197)Beekes.pdf); on the other hand, its surface realization is obvious, [tt] or [ss].

Below is my *summary* of the most relevant research on this problem.

Everyone agrees that θάλασσα is Pre-Greek (i.e. not IE), one of the reasons being that **there were no geminates either in the PIE or in Pre-Greek** (Beekes, Brixhe etc.).

As Stephen Colvin ([Colvin 2007](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/a-historical-greek-reader-9780199226603?cc=us&lang=en&)) writes, "the prehistory of these clusters [i.e. obstruent +y, Alex B.] is complex and much disputed" (p. 26). That being said, the communis opinio seems to be that the underlying consonant to be a palatalized velar, e.g. *-χyᾰ ([Lejeune 1972](https://www.klincksieck.com/livre/1542-phonetique-historique-du-mycenien-et-du-grec-ancien), §98d) or *kʲᾰ (Beekes, kya in his notation); cf. Macedonian (?) θαλάγχα(ν).

[Bubenik 2017](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110261288/9783110261288-040/9783110261288-040.xml) offers a very clear and a rather compelling account of how this might have happened. He writes that dental and velar palatalization, with subsequent affrication, happened in Proto-Greek:

> *tj > *t'j > *t's'j
>
> *kj > *k'j > *t's'j (in his notation).

The palatal glide was later lost, the palatal affricate was depalatalized and merged with Proto-Greek *ts.

This cluster, Bubenik writes, "could be subject to progressive assimilation  *ts > tt* (in Boeotian, Attic and Central Cretan) or to regressive assimilation *ts> ss* (in other dialects)' (p. 647). Thus, he classifies all the dialects into the following groups:

1. Arcado-Cretan and Ionic: PG *k(h)j, tw > ss; PG *t(h)j, *ts and *ss > s;
2. Aeolic and West: all of those > ss;
3. Attica, Euboea, and Boeotia: PG *k(h)j, *tw, and partly **t(h)j > tt.

He speculates that tt "could have belonged to the Aeolic basilect, surviving in Boeotian (and extended to [Western?] Attic), but eliminated partially in Thessalian and wholly in Lesbian" (p. 648).

cf. "geminate tt in Attic is a reflex of part of the palatalization isogloss shared with Boeotian and Euboean, corresponding to the geminate ss of Ionic and other dialects: cf. lexical forms like thálatta ‘sea’, glôtta ‘tongue’ vs. Ion. thálassa, glôssa, or verbal formations like *eret-jō > eréttō ‘I row’ (cf. erétēs ‘rower’), *kāruk-jō > kērúttō ‘I announce’ vs. Ion. eréssō, kērússō" (Angeliki Malikouti-Drachman, [“Phonology (Survey)”](https://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopedia-of-ancient-greek-language-and-linguistics/phonology-survey-COM_00000283?s.num=6), in: Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek Language and Linguistics, 2013).

If you are interested in more dialect data, feel free to peruse Thumb and Scherer  or even Meister.

Answer (score 11):

There have been various theories about the phonetic value of ττ and σσ, but it`s often held that they were pronounced as might be expected, i.e. as [tt] and [ss]. The philologist Sidney Allen argues as follows:

> These facts have led some scholars to suppose that both the ττ of
>   Attic and the σσ of other dialects represent different attempts to
>   write such an affricate without the use of a special symbol; and that
>   the pronunciation as a double plosive or fricative is a post-classical
>   development, based in part at least on the spelling. But apart from
>   the improbability of spelling influence on colloquial speech in
>   antiquity, it is scarcely credible that the existence of an affricate
>   sound would not have been revealed in any inscriptional spelling
>   outside those mentioned above (e.g. as τσ), nor the tradition of it
>   survive in the account of any grammarian. On the other hand it is
>   perfectly feasible for both [tt] and [ss] to develop from an earlier
>   affricate, and there seems therefore no need whatever to assume that
>   the ττ of Attic or the σσ of other dialects mean anything more than
>   they appear to. (Sidney Allen, *Vox Graeca, A Guide to the Pronunciation of Classical Greek*, pg.58)

Geoffrey Horrocks also attributes the values [tt] and [ss] to ττ and σσ.

> [I]t was noted that many of the adopted place names and vocabulary
>   items borrowed from the pre-Greek languages of the Aegean basin had
>   undergone dialectally diagnostic sound changes. The almost certainly
>   borrowed word for ‘sea’ , for example, has the following forms:
>   [image] both of which reveal the
>   dialectally standard products of the palatalization of an original
>   voiceless dental or velar by a following semi - vowel. 3 Consider the
>   example in (6): [image] Allen (1958)
>   explains this divergent dialectal development on the assumption of a
>   generalized heavy palatalization of /t/ in Boeotian: the Attic reflex
>   is then probably due to close contact with Boeotian at the time of the
>   change (on which see further below). But the fact that loanwords such
>   as that in (5) undergo developments identical to those undergone by
>   native vocabulary (even though we cannot, of course, discover the
>   exact form in which such words were first borrowed) strongly suggests
>   that the division of Greek into the historical dialects attested in
>   literature and alphabetic inscriptions had only taken place after all
>   its future speakers had become established in the Aegean area.
>   (Geoffrey Horrocks, *Greek, A History of the Language and its
>   Speakers*, pg.19)

**Additional information:**

Although your question doesn't deal with the following, I thought you might be interested:

> But, like many literary languages, literary Attic was subject to
>   influences from outside the restricted area of the spoken dialect,
>   most particularly from Ionic. And one of the most characteristic
>   features of this influence is the substitution of forms with σσ for
>   the ττ of 'pure' Attic as exemplified by the inscriptions. In fact in
>   tragedy, and in prose works up to and including Thucydides, the ττ of
>   Attic is almost entirely avoided. Even though normal Attic grammar was
>   used, and Attic phonology generally adopted, it seems that the ττ was
>   felt as something of a provincialism by contrast with the σσ of most
>   of the rest of the Greek-speaking world—all the more to be avoided as
>   a characteristic of the speech of the 'συοβοιωτοί'; and even false
>   Ionicisms (notably ἡσσᾶσθαι as against Attic ἡττᾶσθαι and Ionic
>   ἑσσοῦσθαι) were liable to be perpetrated in avoidance of this
>   shibboleth. (Sidney Allen, *Vox Graeca, A Guide to the Pronunciation of Classical Greek*, pg.11)

Comment: Evidence that there was a velar in the "sea" word is the form δαλαγχα cited by Hesychius (thought to be Macedonian because of the initial d-).

Comment: @TKR. Yeah, I was under no illusion that there's unanimous agreement on this matter. Thanks for the input!

Comment: (Just to be clear, that doesn't contradict anything in your answer, but actually reinforces the *kj > tt/ss theory.)